IndexError: list index out of range when executing _get_start_solution in vehicle routing problem
I’m working on a vehicle routing problem implementation, and I’m encountering an IndexError when executing the _get_start_solution function. The error occurs during the final print statement of the solution.
Details:
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hajar\Desktop\lns_v_test_epsilon\lns\test_alpha_gamma.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\hajar\Desktop\lns_v_test_epsilon\lns\test_alpha_gamma.py", line 124, in main
    test(epsilon, gamma, alpha)
  File "C:\Users\hajar\Desktop\lns_v_test_epsilon\lns\test_alpha_gamma.py", line 96, in test
    solution = alg.solve(problem, start_time,type="eps_greedy", method="TS",eps=epsilon, ensemble=[])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hajar\Desktop\lns_v_test_epsilon\lns\algorithm.py", line 704, in solve
    start_solution = self._get_start_solution(problem)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hajar\Desktop\lns_v_test_epsilon\lns\algorithm.py", line 802, in _get_start_solution
    f"Final solution: {solution.routes}, "
  File "C:\Users\hajar\Desktop\lns_v_test_epsilon\lns\solution.py", line 391, in __repr__
    self.earliest[i],
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range'

I have 30 clients in my instance, but it seems that one of the indices is going out of range.
The traceback indicates that the error arises when attempting to access the routes after minimizing the vehicles.
Here’s a snippet of my _get_start_solution function for context:
def _get_start_solution(self, problem):
    """
    Generate an initial solution for the problem by assigning requests to vehicles
    based on vehicle capacity and customer demands.

    Parameters
    ----------
    problem : `Problem`
        The optimization problem containing vehicles and requests.

    Returns
    -------
    solution : `Solution`
        The initial solution object with routes for all vehicles.
    """
    # Initialize the solution object
    solution = Solution(problem)

    num_customers = len(problem.P)  # Number of customers (pickup points)
    print(f"Number of customers: {num_customers}")

    # Default vehicle capacity, adjust if capacity is stored elsewhere in problem
    vehicle_capacity = getattr(problem.vehicles[0], 'capacity', 100)  # Get vehicle capacity from the first vehicle
    print(f"Vehicle capacity: {vehicle_capacity}")

    # Initialize routes and remaining capacities for each vehicle
    routes = []
    capacities = []
    vehicle_id = 0  # Start vehicle IDs from 0

    # Create a list of customers (excluding depot which is assumed to be customer 0)
    customers = list(range(1, num_customers + 1))  # Only customers, not the depot
    print(f"Shuffling customers: {customers}")
    random.shuffle(customers)

    # Create a new route whenever the vehicle is full
    current_route = []
    current_capacity = vehicle_capacity

    # Iterate over the shuffled customers and assign them to vehicles
    for customer_id in customers:
        if customer_id not in problem.P:
            print(f"Customer {customer_id} not found in problem.P")
            continue  # Skip this customer if they do not exist
        # Get the demand of the customer (assuming demand is stored in 'load')
        demand = problem.P[customer_id].load  # Adjust if demand attribute is different
        print(f"Customer {customer_id} demand: {demand}")

        # Check if the current vehicle can accommodate the customer's demand
        if current_capacity >= demand:
            current_route.append(customer_id)
            current_capacity -= demand

            # Remove the customer from the request bank as it is now assigned
            if customer_id in solution.request_bank:
                solution.request_bank.remove(customer_id)
        else:
            # If the current vehicle is full, finalize the current route and start a new one
            if current_route:  # Only append if current_route is not empty
                route = Route(problem, vehicle_id)
                route.route = current_route  # Assign the customers to the route
                routes.append(route)  # Add the completed route to the routes list

            # Start a new route with a new vehicle
            current_route = [customer_id]
            current_capacity = vehicle_capacity - demand

            # Remove the customer from the request bank as it is now assigned
            if customer_id in solution.request_bank:
                solution.request_bank.remove(customer_id)

            # Increment vehicle ID for the next route
            vehicle_id += 1

    # Add the final route (if there are still customers left)
    if current_route:
        route = Route(problem, vehicle_id)
        route.route = current_route  # Assign the customers to the route
        routes.append(route)  # Add the last route to the routes list

    # Check if all requests have been assigned to a route
    if 0 in solution.request_bank:  # Check if depot is in the request bank (shouldn't be)
        solution.request_bank.remove(0)  # Remove depot if present

    if len(solution.request_bank) > 0:
        print(f"Remaining in request bank: {solution.request_bank}")
        raise IndexError("There are not enough vehicles to assign all requests")

    # Filter the routes to include only those that were used
    solution.routes = routes  # Use the routes list created earlier
    print(
         f"Final solution: {solution.routes}, "
         f"Number of routes: {len(solution.routes)}, "
         f"Number of vehicles used: {solution._number_of_used_vehicles()}"
     )
    # Rebuild insert matrices to reflect the current state of the solution
    solution._rebuild_insert_matrices()

    return solution


   def _rebuild_insert_matrices(self):
    """
    (Re)build the insert matrices.

    This method (re)builds _delta_f and _best_insert_position.
    Matrices needed by the insert heuristics.
    """
    # Creating and initializing matrices
    self._delta_f = [[float('inf')]*len(self.routes) for x in range(self.problem.n)]
    self._best_insert_position = [[-1]*len(self.routes) for x in range(self.problem.n)]

    # For each route
    for route_id in self.available_vehicles:
        self._update_best_insert_route(route_id)

I have this data:
    B-n31-k5
runtime: 831.782910
 VEHICLE
 NUMBER     CAPACITY
 100000                     100

CUSTOMER
CUST NO.  XCOORD.    YCOORD.    DEMAND

  0             17                76                 0
  1             24            6              25
  2             96            29             3
  3             14            19            13
  4             14            32            17
  5             0            34              16
  6             16           22            9
  7              20           26            22
  8             22            28            10
  9             17            23            16
 10             98            30              8
 11             30            8              3
 12             23             27           16
 13             19             23            16
 14              34            7             10
 15              31             7            24
 16             0            37            16
 17             19            23             15
 18             0             36              14
 19             26             7             5
 20              98              32            12
 21             5               40         2
 22             17             26              18
 23              21             26             20
 24             28              8            15
 25             1             35            8
 26            27             28            22
 27             99             30            15
 28              26             28              10
 29            17            29            13
 30            20            26            19

Could anyone help me identify why this IndexError is occurring and how I can ensure that all clients are properly included in the solution? Any guidance on managing the routes effectively would be greatly appreciated!
the code of  repr :
    def __repr__(self):
    result = "* Total current cost: %s \n" % self.cost
    result += "* (node: [start, departure_load]):\n"
    for i in range(len(self.route)):
        result += "(%s: [%s, %s]) --> " % (self.route[i],
                                           self.earliest[i],
                                           self.loads[i])
    return result


For more details of the complete code, check https://github.com/corstjens/lns/tree/837cdb7e79c295ce8e44bc53c227a579e55e8112/lns

please include full stacktrace

@folengateis check Edit

please add the code of your __repr__ too

@folengateis check please the Edit

that's not the same code, the error comes from self.earliest[i]

yes :     def repr(self):
result = "* Total current cost: %s \n" % self.cost
result += "* (node: [start, departure_load]):\n"
for i in range(len(self.route)):
result += "(%s: [%s, %s]) --> " % (self.route[i],
self.earliest[i],
self.loads[i])
return result

@folengateis check edit please

It means that self.route is longer than self.earliest. Why is that? Is it intentional?

the aim is simply to generate a random initial solution

Okay, but what about the question I asked for clarification?

@mkrieger1 yes, because we only have capacity constraints and no time constraints

If self.route is intentionally longer than self.earliest, it is a mistake to assume that every i that is a valid index for self.route is also a valid index for self.earliest. You have to think about what you want to do in __repr__ for those extra values in self.route for which there is no value in self.earliest.

@folengateis please, do you have a solution to this problem?

@mkrieger1 please, do you have a solution to this problem ?

No, you must decide what you want to do in __repr__.

This code resolve my problem without changing in repr, just changing the get_start_solution
def _get_start_solution(self, problem):
    """
    Generate an initial solution for the problem by assigning requests to vehicles
    based on vehicle capacity and customer demands.

    Parameters
    ----------
    problem : `Problem`
        The optimization problem containing vehicles and requests.

    Returns
    -------
    solution : `Solution`
        The initial solution object with routes for all vehicles.
    """
    # Initialize the solution object
    solution = Solution(problem)

    num_customers = len(problem.P)  # Number of customers (pickup points)
    print(f"Number of customers: {num_customers}")

    vehicle_capacity = getattr(problem.vehicles[0], 'capacity', 100)  # Get vehicle capacity from the first vehicle
    print(f"Vehicle capacity: {vehicle_capacity}")

    routes = []
    vehicle_id = 0  # Start vehicle IDs from 0

    # Create a list of customers (excluding depot which is assumed to be customer 0)
    customers = list(range(1, num_customers + 1))  # Only customers, not the depot
    print(f"Shuffling customers: {customers}")
    random.shuffle(customers)

    current_route = []
    current_capacity = vehicle_capacity
    current_loads = []  # To keep track of the loads in the current route

    for customer_id in customers:
        if customer_id not in problem.P:
            print(f"Customer {customer_id} not found in problem.P")
            continue  # Skip this customer if they do not exist

        demand = problem.P[customer_id].load  # Assuming demand is stored in 'load'
        print(f"Customer {customer_id} demand: {demand}")

        # Check if the current vehicle can accommodate the customer's demand
        if current_capacity >= demand:
            current_route.append(customer_id)
            current_capacity -= demand
            current_loads.append(demand)  # Track the load for this route

            # Remove the customer from the request bank as it is now assigned
            if customer_id in solution.request_bank:
                solution.request_bank.remove(customer_id)
        else:
            if current_route:  # Only append if current_route is not empty
                route = Route(problem, vehicle_id)
                route.route = current_route
                routes.append(route)

                # Synchronize earliest, latest, and loads with the route length
                route.earliest = [0] * len(current_route)  # Assuming default values for earliest
                route.latest = [0] * len(current_route)    # Assuming default values for latest
                route.loads = current_loads  # Assign the loads

            # Start a new route with a new vehicle
            current_route = [customer_id]
            current_capacity = vehicle_capacity - demand
            current_loads = [demand]  # Reset the load for the new route

            # Remove the customer from the request bank as it is now assigned
            if customer_id in solution.request_bank:
                solution.request_bank.remove(customer_id)

            # Increment vehicle ID for the next route
            vehicle_id += 1

    # Add the final route (if there are still customers left)
    if current_route:
        route = Route(problem, vehicle_id)
        route.route = current_route
        routes.append(route)

        # Synchronize earliest, latest, and loads with the route length
        route.earliest = [0] * len(current_route)
        route.latest = [0] * len(current_route)
        route.loads = current_loads  # Assign the final loads

    # Check if all requests have been assigned to a route
    if 0 in solution.request_bank:  # Check if depot is in the request bank (shouldn't be)
        solution.request_bank.remove(0)

    if len(solution.request_bank) > 0:
        print(f"Remaining in request bank: {solution.request_bank}")
        raise IndexError("There are not enough vehicles to assign all requests")

    solution.routes = routes  # Use the routes list created earlier
    print(
        f"Final solution: {solution.routes}, "
        f"Number of routes: {len(solution.routes)}, "
        f"Number of vehicles used: {solution._number_of_used_vehicles()}"
    )

    # Rebuild insert matrices to reflect the current state of the solution
    solution._rebuild_insert_matrices()

    return solution

